# How to perform object initializer for a list property in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, object-initializers

I am trying to implement object initializer. All the classes are already created by someone else. I cannot change.

I have a class `Ins.vb` that has a list as a property

```
Partial Public Class Ins
  Private itemField As Item1
  Private sizeCodeListField() As SizeCode  'This is the property

  Public Property Item() As Item1
    Get
      Return Me.itemField
    End Get
    Set
      Me.itemField = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property SizeCodeList() As SizeCode()
    Get
      Return Me.sizeCodeListField
    End Get
    Set
      Me.sizeCodeListField = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

`Item1.vb`

```
Public Partial Class Item1
  Private codeField As String
  
  Public Property Code() As String
    Get
      Return Me.codeField
    End Get
    Set
      Me.codeField = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

`SizeCode.vb`

```
Partial Public Class SizeCode
  Private sizeCode1Field As String
  Private sizeCodeDescriptionField As String

  Public Property SizeCode1() As String
    Get
      Return Me.sizeCode1Field
    End Get
    Set
      Me.sizeCode1Field = value
    End Set
  End Property
  Public Property SizeCodeDescription() As String
    Get
      Return Me.sizeCodeDescriptionField
    End Get
    Set
      Me.sizeCodeDescriptionField = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

This is how I am trying to do object initialization

```
Dim myVar = New Ins _
  With {.Item = New Item1 With {.Code = "I"},
        .SizeCodeList = New SizeCode With {.SizeCode1 = "S", .SizeCodeDescription = "Description"}}  'I am getting an error here
```

The error is `Value of type 'SizeCode' cannot be converted to 'SizeCode()'`

I am not sure how to implement this and I am stuck.

Comment: `SizeCodeList` is an array.  Put braces around the `New SizeCode ...` expression so that you are providing an array, and it should work (you'll be assigning an array of length 1 containing the new object that you declared inline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax should be something like this:

```
            Dim myVar = New Ins _
  With {.Item = New Item1 With {.Code = "I"},
        .SizeCodeList = New SizeCode() {New SizeCode With {.SizeCode1 = "S", .SizeCodeDescription = "Description"}}}
```

Comment: The `New SizeCode()` isn't necessary, VB will infer it from the array that follows.

Comment: @Craig but it makes it cleaner

Answer (score -1):

You are initializing .SizeCodelist as a SizeCode but it should be a list.
I did not test it but this should work I think:

```
 Dim myVar = New Ins With
{.Item = New Item1 With {.Code = "I"},
 .SizeCodeList = New List(Of SizeCode)}

Dim newSizeCode As New SizeCode With {.SizeCode1 = "S", .SizeCodeDescription = "Description"}

myvar.SizeCodeList.add(newSizeCode)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because the member is an array, not a list.